# How to give multi select for foreign key without many to many field or through table django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

```
class StudentPlatformDefaultDocuments(models.Model):
    id       = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Documents, db_column='DocumentId')
```

I am trying to give multi select in forms.py, but it does not work.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
        document = self.cleaned_data['document']
        print(document,'document get')
        instance= super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit=False) 
        if document:
            documents = []
            for doc in document:
                print(doc,'doc1212121')
                print(doc.documentid,'doc1212121')
                document1 = Documents.objects.get(
                    documentid=doc.documentid).documentid
                print(document1,'document1')
                documents.append(document1)
                test = StudentPlatformDefaultDocuments.objects.create(
                    document=doc.documentid)
                test.save()
            print(documents)
            return instance
```

Tried overriding save method in `forms.py` but getting error.

Comment: I think your need like this.....???

https://codepen.io/w3programmings/pen/OJVrBZR

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full Error Traceback to it.